# match two sections of string using SED

Tags: sed

I need to print only the sections I want from a string. For example:

```
10/11/12 05:34:34 Writer has an issue. Check this info [Avg. 12 write issues found]
```

I want to match `"10/11/12 05:34:34 Writer"` and `"[Avg. 12 write issues found]"`
Writer sometimes can be Reader, so I need to consider that also. Regexp are ovbiously required, but nothing I have tried with sed gets me both sections of the string. BTW, I use solaris 10 so the sed version there does not support the -r parameter :(

I currently process the string twice and put the result in a variable so I can print both variables at the end. However, I want to do this in a single line of code

How can I print two sections I need from a string?

Thank you

Comment: You want to print the entire line when it has both of those bits or just those matching bits? What about those bits can change exactly? The date/time stamp presumably. You already mentioned `Writer`/`Reader`. The number of issues? `write`/`read` in the bracketed bit too?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -r 's/^(.*(Reader|Writer)).*(\[.*\])/\1 \3/' file
```

Finally :

```
$ oIFS="$IFS"
$ IFS=$'\n'; arr=( $(sed -r 's/^(.*(Reader|Writer)).*(\[.*\])/\1\n\3/' file) )
$ IFS="$oIFS"
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
10/11/12 05:34:34 Writer
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
[Avg. 12 write issues found]
```

### edit

without `-r` :

```
sed 's/^\(.*\(Reader\|Writer\)\).*\(\[.*\]\)/\1\n\3/' file
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using -r? I use Solaris and the sed version there doesn't support -r :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find the two pattern and print them together without using -r value as follows

```
sed 's#\([0-9]\{2\}.*:[0-9]\{2\} \S*\).*\(\[.*\]\)#\1 \2#g'
```

Results

```
10/11/12 05:34:34 Writer [Avg. 12 write issues found]
```

Matching **Writer** or **Reader** without using -r option with sed

```
sed -e 's#\([0-9]\{2\}.*:[0-9]\{2\} Writer\).*\(\[.*\]\)#\1 \2#g' -e 's#\([0-9]\{2\}.*:[0-9]\{2\} Reader\).*\(\[.*\]\)#\1 \2#g' my_file
```